# InfoBox labels don't offset as expected

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the InfoBox class from the Utilities Library of the Google Maps V3 API for making labels that are associated with points.

Now, my goal is to have the labels flow neatly around a point, but as you can see, this isn't happening:

[Image](http://i47.tinypic.com/w0kode.jpg)

As you can see from the InfoBox specification, pixelOffset takes a Size object ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size ). The docs don't say a whole lot about which values are accepted. (I, of course, want negative values.)

First, I have an array with offset values:

```
var arr = [
  {x: -25, y: -25},
  {x: -25, y: 0},
  {x: -25, y: 25},
  {x: 0, y: -25},
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 0, y: 25},
  {x: 25, y: -25},
  {x: 25, y: 0},
  {x: 25, y: 25}
];
```

Then, a position:

```
var lat = 58.9030277;
var lng = 5.7114827999999990;
```

Finally, a loop generates the markers and the offsets:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  });

  var myOptions = {
    content: '#' + (i + 1),
    disableAutoPan: true,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(arr[i].x, arr[i].y),
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  };

  ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
}
```

Does anyone understand this behavior? Is there a better way to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your offsets is that you assume a wrong default-position of the label, the label is not centered on the position, it's placed below the point(the middle of the top-border of the infobox is placed at the position)

To get an exact result you must know the width/height of the marker and of the infoboxes(assuming both are squares).
Furthermore the width/height of the marker must be divisible by 2 and width/height of the label must be divisible by 3(first problem here, it seems as if the width/height of the infobox is 25).

The first marker(top left) must be placed at:

```
{x:-(widthOrHeightOfInfoBox*1.5),
 y:-((widthOrHeightOfInfoBox*1.5)+(widthOrHeightOfMarker/2))}
```

For the other markers add widthOrHeightOfInfoBox to x or y(depending on row/col)

Assuming the marker has a width/height of 10 and the infoBox a width/height of 24(remember, it has to be divisble by 3), this should give the desired result:

```
var arr = [
  {x: -36, y: -41},
  {x: -36, y: -17},
  {x: -36, y:   7},
  {x: -12, y: -41},
  {x: -12, y: -17},
  {x: -12, y:   7},
  {x:  12, y: -41},
  {x:  12, y: -17},
  {x:  12, y:   7}
];
```